# How can I convert these tags and attributes to aspx.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i would want convert the following html code in aspx with Response.Write and tags + attributes.

```
<p class="inline-medium-label button-height">
    <span class="label">Large with stripes</span>
    <span class="demo-progress large" data-progress-options='{"size":false,"style":"large","barClasses":["green-gradient","glossy"],"innerMarks":25,"stripes":true,"darkStripes":false}'>100%</span>
</p>
```

Ho can i convert it leaving intact the single quotes? Thanks!!
Thanks again!
Cris

Comment: What kind of "conversion" are you talking about? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: And why you need to keep single quotes, you could use double quotes and escape the double quotes in the content. If you want to print this with `Response.Write`, just do it and escape your double quotes, at all.

Comment: Just by adding this in the question, **Please it's urgent**, usually speeds up the answers, the detail is not so important!

Comment: The errors are that is expected the sign ), ; and ) is not a valid term into the expression...why? Thanks why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly response.write it:

```
Response.Write("<p class=\"inline-medium-label button-height\">");
Response.Write("    <span class=\"label\">Large with stripes</span>");
Response.Write("    <span class=\"demo-progress large\" data-progress-options='{\"size\":false,\"style\":\"large\",\"barClasses\":[\"green-gradient\",\"glossy\"],\"innerMarks\":25,\"stripes\":true,\"darkStripes\":false}'>100%</span>");
Response.Write("</p>");
```

If you are using an HtmlTextWriter, you can use the AddAttribute/RenderBeginTag methods to render data, but then you have no control over the markup, and so I don't think that would work.

It really depends on the context of where this code is at to provide the best answer possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and precise answer. Thank you ^ 1000 times!